# how to perform datagridview cellclick event from datagriview keypress event?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, event-handling

```
     private void item_grid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.ColumnIndex==taxone_col_index || e.ColumnIndex==taxtwo_col_index)
        {


        }

    }

    private void item_grid_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
        {
            e.Handled = true;

           item_grid.CellClick; // i did this but its not working            }
    }
```

i want to perform the cell click event from keypress event. how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to know the row and column index of the cell that the key is pressed in. From that you will then be able to look up the value of the cell.

To do this just use the `CurrentCell` property of the `DataGridView`.

Trying to artificially create a `CellClick` is just asking for trouble.

One thing to note is that you will probably need to handle the `EditingControlShowing` event and attach a `KeyPress` handler to the underlying editing control since typing into a `DataGridView` cell does not raise the grid level `KeyPress` event.

---

If you **really** want to create a `CellClick` event you will need to subclass the `DataGridView` control, and create your own `RaiseCellClick()` method which then calls the protected `OnCellClick()` method:

```
public void RaiseCellClick(int row, int column)
{
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e = new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(row, column);
    base.OnCellClick(e);
}
```

But even this doesn't particularly help you since the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` needs to take the row and column indexes in its constructor.